# Split assets by ABI on Android

Tags: android, native, assets

I've seen [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split) on how to build split APKs for each ABI.

However my app embeds a bunch of native executables as assets. Is it possible to filter them based on the ABI?

Relevant parts of `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
            // builds assets and places them in src/main/assets
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Sample app tree after building native executables with CMake:

```
src
  + main
      + assets
          + x86
          |   + native-x86.bin
          + x86_64
          |   + native-x86_64.bin
          + armeabi-v7a
          |   + native-arm.bin
          + arm64-v8a
              + native-aarch64.bin
```

Each ABI directory contains native binaries

I would like each split APK to contain only the ABI-specific assets directory, with the other ones filtered. For example, for the arm64 APK:

```
assets
   + arm64-v8a
       + native-aarch64.bin
```

Comment: There used to be a recipe for doing this using product flavors, though I have not researched the point recently.

Answer (score 0):

check this [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds)

One solution is to use Flavors.(didn't test this)

```
  productFlavors {

   x86 {
    jniLibs.srcDir = /path/to/native-x86.bin
    //or maybe 
    assets.srcDirs = /path/to/native-x86.bin
     ndk {
      abiFilter "x86"
    }
   }
   armv7 {
    jniLibs.srcDir = /path/to/native-arm.bin
    ndk {
    abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
  }
  }
```

Hope that will help you.